# Android MenuItem setVisible

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to hide/show menuItem but getting NPE. It works in onPrepareOptionsMenu but not in onCreate. By default it should be invisible.

e.g. in my fragment's onCreate i would like to do something like:

```
if (condition) menuItem.setvisible(true);
```

but it gets me NPE on that menuItem.

Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.inventory_list_toolbar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_inventory);

    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.inventory_list_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.inventory_list_menu_add);
    menuItem.setVisible(false);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide menu from onCreate method since it's not inflated yet.

You should make your logic in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (condition) {
        // do what you want
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_id);
        menuItem.setvisible(true);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Otherwise, put your logic in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when you need to refresh something.

Comment: yes, i did it in my fragment and it is working, but it's not working from any other method. and how do i make onPrepareOptionsMenu boolean in fragment?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can't make it returns a boolean since it returns void. Have you tried to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: yes, getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); wherever i could put it, i get NPE all the time. and in onPrepare i cannot return anything, it is void and it is in fragment

Comment: Call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your fragments onCreate() . Then onPrepareOptionsMenu() will call for fragment and you can change the visibility of MenuItems

Answer (score -1):

```
private Menu menu;
```

Then initialize it as

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
this.menu = menu;
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
return true;
}
```

When u want to hide/show the menu use

```
if(menu != null){ 
MenuItem item_up = menu.findItem(R.id.action_up); 
item_up.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Declare Menu menu;' Then initialize it as  @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  this.menu = menu;
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }
When u want to hide/show the menu use   
    if(menu != null){
     MenuItem item_up = menu.findItem(R.id.action_up);
     item_up.setVisible(true);
    }

Comment: @AkshayChopde: Edit the answer with the explanation, don't add it as a comment